# How to get the users id with the command userinfo (discord bots)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm very new to coding, and I'm experiencing a problem with my code. I'm using JS and my very first language. With my code, if you try and use the user's ID with the command userinfo it does the author's userinfo instead of the id of the person you did.

```
    bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const member = message.guild.member(user);
    const joinDiscord = moment(user.createdAt).format('llll');
    const joinServer = moment(user.joinedAt).format('llll');
    const prefix = '/'; 

    if (message.author.bot) return; 
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return; 
    if (!user) user = message.user;

    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "USERINFO")) {
        roles = member.roles.map(roles => roles).filter(r => r.id!=message.guild.id).sort((b,a) => a.position-b.position).join(' **|** ')

        if (roles == "" || roles == undefined) {
            roles = "`No Roles Available`"
        }
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(user.username + '#' + user.discriminator, user.displayAvatarURL)
            .addField('ID', user.id)
            .addField('Nickname', `${member.nickname !== null ? `${member.nickname}` : 'None'}`, true)
            .addField('Status', `${user.presence.status}`, true)
            .addField('Bot', `${user.bot}`, true)
            .addField('Roles', roles)
            .addField('Joined At', `${moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format("MMMM, Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}`,)
            .addField('Created At', `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("MMMM, Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}`,)
            .setThumbnail(`${user.avatarURL}`)
            .setColor(0x33B5FF)

        message.channel.send(embed);  

    } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `message.guild.members.get()` for discord v11 and `message.guild.members.cache.get()` for discord v12

```js
   bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; 
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return; 
    let targetMember;
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    if(args.length === 0) {
        targetMember = message.member;
    } else {
        targetMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
    }
    if(!targetMember) targetMember = message.member

    const joinDiscord = moment(targetMember.user.createdAt).format('llll');
    const joinServer = moment(targetMember.joinedAt).format('llll');
    const prefix = '/'; 

    if (message.startsWith(prefix + "USERINFO")) {
        roles = targetMember.roles.map(roles => roles).filter(r => r.id!=message.guild.id).sort((b,a) => a.position-b.position).join(' **|** ')

        if (roles == "" || roles == undefined) {
            roles = "`No Roles Available`"
        }
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(targetMember.user.username + '#' + targetMember.user.discriminator, targetMember.user.displayAvatarURL)
            .addField('ID', targetMember.id)
            .addField('Nickname', `${targetMember.nickname !== null ? `${targetMember.nickname}` : 'None'}`, true)
            .addField('Status', `${targetMember.user.presence.status}`, true)
            .addField('Bot', `${targetMember.user.bot}`, true)
            .addField('Roles', roles)
            .addField('Joined At', `${moment.utc(targetMember.joinedAt).format("MMMM, Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}`,)
            .addField('Created At', `${moment.utc(targetMember.user.createdAt).format("MMMM, Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}`,)
            .setThumbnail(`${targetMember.user.avatarURL}`)
            .setColor(0x33B5FF)
        message.channel.send(embed);  
    } 

});
```